# Start a Function at a specific time range

Tags: python, datetime, schedule

I need to run a specific funtion every 5 minutes, starting on Sunday night at 11pm until Friday 11pm.
How can I do it? I tried with "schedule" module, below a general function that print the instant time

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

def script_sample():
  now = datetime.now()
  print(now)

schedule.every(5).minutes.sunday.at("23:00").until.friday.at("23:00").do(script_sample)
while True:
  schedule.run_pending()
```

But I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'friday'
```

How can I do it? Is "schedule" the right module for this task?

Comment: You you be able to simply set p a Task Scheduler and let the computer run the python script every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly set until condition as the day of week and time in schedule API but can set an explicit datetime, time, or a timedelta object as an argument in the `until()` function. See [apidocs](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#run-a-job-until-a-certain-time).

Also, you cannot schedule a job with a day of week and every x minutes.
Something like `schedule.every(5).minutes.sunday.at("23:00")` is not allowed.

Try something like this to first find the date of next Sunday then calculate the following Friday date from it. Now you have the starting and ending times.

Next, you can call sleep until the start time then you can start to schedule the job.

```python
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import schedule

def script_sample():
    now = datetime.now()
    print(now)

now = datetime.now()
# find date of next sunday
d = now
# weekday():  Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6
while d.weekday() != 6:
    d += timedelta(days=1)
d = d.replace(hour=23, minute=00, second=0, microsecond=0)
print("now=", now)
print("next sunday", d) # start date
wait_time = d - now

wait_time_secs = wait_time.total_seconds()
if wait_time_secs > 0:
    print("wait time is ", wait_time)
    print("waiting to start...")
    time.sleep(wait_time_secs)
else:
    print("no need to wait. let's get started')
```

This part of the code will be complete when it is Sunday at 23:00 or just late on Sunday if it was started on Sunday after 23:00.

Part 2 of the code below is to determine the until condition and schedule the job to run. Next find the date of next Friday which is the until condition in the schedule. Finally schedule the job to run every 5 minutes until Friday at 23:00.

```python
# next find date of next Friday (friday=5)
while d.weekday() != 5:
    d += timedelta(days=1)
endtime = d.replace(hour=23, minute=00, second=0, microsecond=0)
print("end time", endtime)

# now schedule a job every 5 mins until the end time
schedule.every(5).minutes.until(endtime).do(script_sample)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```